# Java chart library for really large data?

Tags: java, charts

I'm looking for a chart library capable to handle large amount of data points - 300 millions per a chart and even more. Surely drawing, caching and approximation should be implemented with intelligence there.

Actually I need to represent waveforms but *not only* them.

Target platform is Java, data comes from files.

UPD: PC, Swing.

Comment: Reading 300m co-ords from flat files is going to take some time. And given the limited resolutions of screens is it really necessary to read all of them?

Comment: It is *not* necessary; at least some work could be completed asynchronously.

Answer (score 3):

Not java, but CERN does massive data crunching and distros/plots may well have these kinds of data volumes. They use the [root](http://root.cern.ch/) package which is c++. You can download it, although couldn't see a licence. It's prob open source.

Or alternatively, take a look at [R](http://www.r-project.org/) which might do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to handle that amount of data on an android phone, whatever librairy you use. You should think about doing all this processing on a server or a cloud and then put either an approximated set of data that would approximate the chart or even the result of the chart as an image file so that android phones can download it from the server without processing the data.

Regards,
 stéphane

Comment: The OP says nothing about android or phones.

Comment: I'm not talking about Android. The best C++ based programs needs five minutes to draw such a chart on my PC; so I don't think a cloud is needed in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I have been happy with my use of [JChart2D](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/). Switching to it from JFreeChart saved us considerable processor use, and it has traces that compute multiple inputs into a mean point for speed and memory saving. I've never used them seeing as how I haven't needed to yet. I have put extremely large sets of data into a normal trace by accident, and it didn't seem to be a problem.

There may be a better charting system out there, but this one gets the job done quick and effectively, it's free, open-source, based off of JPanels, and the author is around to answer questions and correct problems.

Comment: what maximum dataset size you plotted using jchart2d? I am doing the same but memory consumption seems to be the problem.

Comment: I don't work for that company anymore, haven't for around six years. I think it was on the order of the asker's data, in the hundreds of millions, in real time, at a few hundred or less a second. But I can't recommend anything Java to help out with memory consumption, you'll have to find someone who isn't glad to not be working with that language anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are talking about a Swing Application.

I make use of [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/products/details.html) for all my Swing applications including Graphs and Charts.
Takes a bit getting use to it, but once you are use to it building UI's is fairly quick and easy.

The only problem is that there is a [developer license cost](http://www.jgoodies.com/products/purchase.html) involved.

You can download the Java Webstart examples to have a look at what it is capable of.

Comment: I know there are some libraries - the question is "Are they able to do handle 300M data points?" If someone could confirm JGoodies is able - that would be useful for me.

Comment: I have mailed these guys weeks ago asking about the max handle data points, no answer.